# Need custom input fields for wordpress woocommerce plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, textinput

I am using `WordPress woocommerce plugin` to make a `eCommerce site`. Everything is good about `woocommerce plugin`. But when I saw the `register` section where a user will make `register all of his details`, there is no `custom fields` like `gender, phone no, address etc`. I need all this things in the `register page`. So how to do that? Any help an suggestions will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 3):

This plugin is what youre looking for http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/. You will be able to add extra fields in the registration form and also add it in the user profile page of the user.

Heres a screenshot of a sample registration form http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/screenshots/

I personally use this here http://mayumibeats.com/wp-signup.php?blog_id=1

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own fields adding the following code into your wordpress theme functions.php file.

```
/**
 * Add new register fields for WooCommerce registration.
 *
 * @return string Register fields HTML.
 */
function wooc_extra_register_fields() {
    ?>

    <p class="form-row form-row-first">
    <label for="reg_billing_first_name"><?php _e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_first_name" id="reg_billing_first_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-last">
    <label for="reg_billing_last_name"><?php _e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_last_name" id="reg_billing_last_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
    <label for="reg_billing_phone"><?php _e( 'Phone', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_phone" id="reg_billing_phone" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_phone'] ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <?php
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start', 'wooc_extra_register_fields' );
```

You can modify the fields to be textbox, radiobutton or anything than you need.

Hope it helps :)

Manu.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to edit the plugin files to have this feature. Files that might need changes are

- templates/form-checkout.php
- classes/class-wc-checkout.php

Database changes wont be required as the entries will be saved in wp_usermeta table.

In case if you are registering users via Wordpress's registration page, then use a plugin like [Cimy User Extra Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/)

Comment: Editing the plugin files will prevent the user from updates in the future or the updates will override his changes